# jQuery settings style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the below jQuery script:

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var info = $(this).attr("rel");
    var reference = this;
    if ($(this).hasClass('listed')) {
        // alert('follow');
        $(".unlisted").addClass("unlisted-bw");
        $(".special").addClass("special-bw");
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('special')) {
        // alert('follow');
        $(".unlisted").addClass("unlisted-bw");
        $(".listed").addClass("listed-bw");
    }   

    if ($(this).hasClass('unlisted')) {
        // alert('follow');
        $(".listed").addClass("listed-bw");
        $(".special").addClass("special-bw");
    }            
});
```

I want it to work in a way that if I click on one span (`special`, `listed` or `unlisted`), The other spans to be inactive. How can I do this with jQuery ?

I created this script but not working correctly.
http://jsfiddle.net/3nsrd/

Comment: What do you mean by other spans to be inactive?  Do you mean you simply cannot click on the other ones once you have chosen one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all of the other spans using `.siblings()`. Here's an example:

```
$('span').click(function(e) {   
    $(this).removeClass('special-bw')
            .siblings("span")
            .addClass('special-bw');
});​
```

**DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/3nsrd/4/**

This doesn't include adding their individual hover classes, which could be done by doing a `$.each` on each of the siblings and using their title (or another attribute)

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
    //get the name of the selected span
    selectedSpan = $(this).attr("title");

    //remove class of selected span -bw (i.e. special-bw);
    $(this).removeClass(selectedSpan+'-bw')
           .siblings("span").each(function(){
            //foreach of the other spans, add their name + bw
           $(this).addClass($(this).attr("title")+'-bw');
        });
});​
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3nsrd/6/**

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a quick and simple bit of javascript which will do what you need I believe:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //When the DOM is ready
    $('span').on('click', function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass("disabled")) {
            $this.siblings().addClass("disabled");
        }
    });
});​
```

Basically I add a class disabled to the siblings which can then be styled with:

```
.disabled {
    background:#ccc;
    cursor:default;
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/uBSX6/

Answer (score 0):

I think this fiddle will suit your needs:

http://jsfiddle.net/3nsrd/3/

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    var classes = ['listed', 'special', 'unlisted'];

    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(classes[i])) {
            for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
                if (classes[j] != classes[i]) {
                    $(parent).find('.' + classes[j]).addClass(classes[j] + '-bw');
                }
            }
            $(this).removeClass(classes[i] + '-bw');
            break;
        }
    }          
});​
```

or an even shorter version without a nested loop:

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    var classes = ['listed', 'special', 'unlisted'];

    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(classes[i])) {
            $(parent).find(':not(.' + classes[i] + ')').each(function() {
                $(this).addClass($(this).prop('class') + '-bw');
            });
            $(this).removeClass(classes[i] + '-bw');
            break;
        }
    }          
});​
```